# Type casting before inserting in database?

Tags: php, mysql, int, typecasting-operator

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$day = '3'; // form input 

...

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$q = 'INSERT INTO recording (release_day) VALUES(?)';
$stmt->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $day);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

The variable **$day** is a string from a form input, but i'm binding it to an integer. The database column is a smallint datatype.

I'm assuming the database is getting an integer, right?
Do i need to do some sort of type casting before the binding?
What is consider to be a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to do some sort of type casting before the binding?

You are already doing type casting here:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $day);
```

This coerces `$day` into an integer, because of the first parameter value `'i'` and then passes that value to the database.

For example, if your variable were `'123hello'`, only `123` would be passed.

Comment: thanks! that is what i need it to know, if the bind_param overrides all of the other types. It does!

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1; // PHP Casts to integer because the lack of quote marks for example.
$i = "1"; // PHP Casts to string because of the quote marks 
$i = 1.39; // PHP Casts to float because of the decimal place
```

These are an automatic data cast when you have created the variable, so there is no need to have a secondary cast for your variable, just review over the MySQL manual to see the limitations/max byte size of a smallint. Ensure that you make the servers criteria and you wont have a problem http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: so, what am i inserting, a string or a integer?

Comment: @Marco This is from the PHP interpreter, thats the castings. Your string will be converted to the integer cast type, eg $var = (int) "12"; when binding a integer. Your query will succeed without an error because your variable is able to cast to string

Comment: although the $day is string, it will be inserted as an integer in your statement.